# Mysql Chain Select Query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with a table which looks somewhat like this :

```
Root   |   Connector
  A    |      B
  B    |      C
  C    |      D
  D    |      E
  E    |      -
```

So i want to retrieve the chain for any given root till the connector is blank

For example : Chain of A means a->B->C->D->E whereas Chain of C means C->D->E

I am using mysql database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just try with loop structure in Mysql and got success. Posting to share only--

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `root_connect`(IN init char(1),OUT str char(15))
BEGIN
    set @startChar:=(select connector from tableName where root = init);
    set @endloop := "no";
    set @fullchar:= @startChar;
    set @newchar:= "";  
    if (@startChar !="-" OR @startChar =null) then 
        WHILE (@endloop = "no") DO                  
            set @newchar :=(select connector from tableName where root = @startChar);       
            if(@newchar = '-') THEN
                set @endloop := "yes";
            else
                set @fullchar:= concat(@fullchar,"-",@newchar);
            end if;         
            set @startChar := @newchar;     
        END WHILE;
    end if;
        select @fullchar;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL does not allow the users to create a recursive function, let me show you using stored procedure:

Assuming the table you are working on is named "test".

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS build_chain$$
CREATE PROCEDURE build_chain(init CHAR(1))
BEGIN
    IF init != '-' THEN
        SET @r := (SELECT DISTINCT(root) FROM test WHERE root = init);
        SET @search_type := TRUE;
        SET @result := @r;
    END IF;

    SET @r := (SELECT DISTINCT(connector) FROM test WHERE root = @r AND connector != '-');
    SET @result = CONCAT_WS('->', @result, @r);
    SET @search_type = IF(@search_type, FALSE, TRUE);
    IF @r IS NOT NULL THEN CALL build_chain('-'); ELSE SELECT @result AS result_chain; END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
CALL build_chain('a');
```

Result (the chain) is stored in @result variable.

Note: you can also build the chain using programming language other than MySQL.

Comment: Hi Husni... i did create this store procedure, but i am unable to execute these commands : 
SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
CALL build_chain('a');