# Parents tree in mysql table (while-loop)

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, select, while-loop

Sorry for my English.
I have a mysql table like this

```
[ --------------------------]
[ parent_id ] [ category_id ]
[ --------------------------]
```

---

Site structured like this:

```
0
-> 1
-> 2
-> -> 3
-> -> -> 5
-> 4
```

and table will look like

```
0 1
0 2
2 3
0 4
3 5
```

How to write mysql while loop to input 5 and get list of it's parents until 0:

```
3
2
```

I know, how to write it in php, but I want to do only 1 query to database, but when I try to run "While" examples from official manuals, it returns a lot of errors.

Comment: recursive joins are not possible in mysql afaik, you will have to do it in php or change the structure of your tables, (add a column for the highest parent of any node, then build the tree in php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-parent-child-relationship-in-an-effective-and-easy-way

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913595/chain-select-query/13993704#13993704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every answers are incorrect, but I've done it.
If somebody will need, try this.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dbName`.`getParentsTree` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `tableName`.`getParentsTree` (IN firstChild INT, OUT tree VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  set @newChar = (select `parent_id` from tableName where category_id = firstChild);
  set @fullchar = "";
  set @fullchar = @fullchar + firstChild;
  WHILE (@newChar != 0) DO
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', @fullChar, @newChar) INTO @fullChar;
    set @newChar = (select `parent_id` from tableName where category_id = @newChar);
  END WHILE;
  SELECT @fullchar INTO tree;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL dbName.getParentsTree(46, @a);
SELECT @a;
```

Comment: Hi, what is meant "46" for ?

Comment: @M.Pancadewa thats tree root id.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Procedures..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `root_connect`(IN init char(1),OUT str char(15))
BEGIN
    set @startChar:=(select category_id from tableName where parent_id = init);
    set @endloop := "no";
    set @fullchar:= @startChar;
    set @newchar:= "";  
    if (@startChar !="-" OR @startChar =null) then 
        WHILE (@endloop = "no") DO                  
            set @newchar :=(select category_id from tableName where parent_id = @startChar);       
            if(@newchar = '-') THEN
                set @endloop := "yes";
            else
                set @fullchar:= concat(@fullchar,"-",@newchar);
            end if;         
            set @startChar := @newchar;     
        END WHILE;
    end if;
        select @fullchar;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok putting your answers together I created this one:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dbName`.`getParentsTree` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `dbName`.`getParentsTree` (IN firstChild INT, OUT tree VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  set @newChar = (select `parent_id` from categories where id = firstChild);
  set @newName = (select `name` from categories where id = firstChild);
  set @fullchar = "" + @newName;
  WHILE (@newChar != 0) DO

    set @newChar = (select `parent_id` from categories where id = @newChar);
    set @newName = (select `name` from categories where id = @newChar);
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(' > ', @fullChar, @newName) INTO @fullChar;
  END WHILE;
  SELECT @fullchar INTO tree;
  END $$
  DELIMITER ;
```

To access the procedure

```
 CALL dbName.getParentsTree(460, @tree);
select @tree;
```