# yii or mysql or php get all sub category tree

Tags: php, mysql, yii, tree

table in mysql:

```
id | name        | prent
----------------------------
1  | cat1        | 0
2  | cat1.1      | 1
3  | cat2.1      | 1
4  | cat11.2     | 2
5  | cat11.4     | 4
6  | cat1        | 0
```

i want when select id 1(cat1),I want to get All sub-categories ID . result: "2,3,4,5"

Comment: you can do it with query. You need to write procedure for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204461/parents-tree-in-mysql-table-while-loop

Comment: i want get child id, no parent

Answer (score 0):

if you need select all sub-categories add column path

```
id | name        | parent | path
-----------------------------------
1  | cat1        | 0      | 0-1
2  | cat1.1      | 1      | 0-1-2
3  | cat2.1      | 1      | 0-1-3
4  | cat11.2     | 2      | 0-1-2-4
5  | cat11.4     | 4      | 0-1-2-4-5
6  | cat1        | 0      | 0-6
```

and query:

```
SELECT * FROM tree WHERE path LIKE '0-1-%' ORDER BY path ASC;

path_parent = concat('0','-',id_parent)

path_child = concat('path_parent', '-', 'id_child')
```