# How to use recursion in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a MySQL table called `EmpList`. I want to use loop to bring result as I expected. For example EmpList having two columns,

```
    EmpNo   ReportingTo
    -------------------
    27      14
    68      14
    104     27
    105     27
    138     27
    139     68
    150     8
    151     8
    8       5
```

I am giving `EmpNo` as input to the query (ex: 14). I am expecting who are all `ReportingTo` `EmpNo14` (ex:27,68 from table) and along with it subreportees if any (`EmpNo` who are all `ReportingTo` 27 and 68 (ex:104,105,138 `ReportingTo` 27 and 139 `ReportingTo` 68)). Finally I am trying to get result in a single column like

```
    EmpNo
    ------
    27
    68
    104
    105
    138
    139
```

I am trying to get result using query like this

```
SELECT EmpNo
FROM EmpList
WHERE ReportingTo IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT EmpNo
  FROM EmpList
  WHERE ReportingTo = 14
);
```

This query gives only one level (lowerlevel) result. Input value I am getting dynamically based on login.

Comment: Mysql does not support recursive CTEs and does not provide other vendor specific ways of performing recursive queries.

Comment: See this question about recursion in MySQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345909/mysql-recursion

Comment: This is about how you structure data. I would suggest that you switch to a nested set or perhaps closure tables. These should give you much more flexibility and allow you to do what is required in one query. here is a pretty good starting point for yu http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: While I would suggest the nested set method mentioned by @IanWood is a good solution, another possibility is to use a recursive stored procedure to retrieve the data.

Comment: personally I would avoid recursion at all costs but if the solution and problem are simple enough then by all means...

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913595/chain-select-query/13993704#13993704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need 2 levels - your solution is Union, but for more levels - there is no pretty way to do it in a single query. 
You can always try store procedure to retrieve this data.

for just 2 level information use

```
SELECT EmpNo     
   FROM EmpList 
   WHERE ReportingTo=14 
UNION ALL
SELECT EmpNo
   FROM EmpList
   WHERE ReportingTo IN
       (SELECT DISTINCT EmpNo
            FROM EmpList
            WHERE ReportingTo = 14
       );
```

And in Mysql is better to use join rather than a subquery, therefore the query should be

```
SELECT EmpNo
 FROM EmpList
 WHERE ReportingTo =14
UNION ALL
SELECT l1.EmpNo
 FROM EmpList l1 join EmpList l2 on l1.ReportingTo=l2.EmpNo
 WHERE l2.ReportingTo =14;
```

Comment: As of now my table data contains 2 levels only. I try with stored procedure for better results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `Databasename`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getlist`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getlist`(IN empid INT)
BEGIN
      DROP TABLE IF  EXISTS finallist1;
      DROP TABLE IF  EXISTS finallist2;
          CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS finallist1 (empnumber INT , isread BOOL );
          CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS finallist2 (empnumber INT  );
          INSERT INTO finallist1 (empnumber , isread ) SELECT EmpNo , FALSE  FROM EmpList WHERE reportingTo  IN (empid);
          INSERT INTO finallist2 SELECT EmpNo  FROM EmpList WHERE reportingTo  IN (empid);
          WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM finallist1 WHERE isread = FALSE > 0 )
          DO
          INSERT INTO finallist2 SELECT EmpNo  FROM EmpList WHERE reportingTo  IN (SELECT empnumber FROM finallist1 WHERE isread = FALSE);
          UPDATE finallist1 SET isread = TRUE WHERE empnumber IN (SELECT empnumber FROM finallist2);
          END WHILE ;
          SELECT empnumber FROM finallist2 ;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

//Calling procedure

```
Call getlist(empid);
```